# Proof verification of Buchberger criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, ideals, computational-mathematics

Buchberger's criterion states

**Theorem:** Let $G=\{g_1,g_2,\dots g_r \}$ be a generating set of the ideal $I\trianglelefteq k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]=R$, in the polynomial ring over field $k$ in $n$ variables. Let $>$ be a monomial order on $k[x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n]$. Then $G$ is a Grobner basis iff $S(g_i,g_j):=\frac{\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_i,in_>g_j)}{in_>g_i}g_i-\frac{\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_i,in_>g_j)}{in_>g_j}g_j$ leaves remainder $0$ after applying the division algorithm w.r.t $(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_r)$. [For $f\in R$, $in_>f :=$ the leading term of $f$ with respect to the monomial order $>$]

**Proof:** I shall prove the relatively harder direction, namely if $S(g_i,g_j)$ leave remainder $0$ on division by $(g_1,g_2,\dots ,g_r)$, then $G$ is a Grobner basis. Let $f\in I$ be such that $in_>f\not \in \langle \{in_>g_i : i=1(1)r \} \rangle $. $\because  f\in I$, we can get an expression of the form $\displaystyle{f=\sum_{i=1}^rh_ig_i}$ where $h_i$'s are from $R$. Among all such expressions, consider those so that $\displaystyle{}\max_{1\leq i\leq r}in_>(h_ig_i)$ is minimum, say $\mu$. Further choose an expression from above so that $\# \{i : in_> (h_ig_i)=\mu \}$ is minimum. 
 Let $f=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^rh_ig_i}$ be one such expression. Then clearly we have $in_{>}f\leq \mu $. Moreover, since $in_> g_j \ | \ \mu $ for some $j$ whereas $in_>g_i \not | \ in_> f  $ for any $i$ we get that $in_> f< \mu $. Thus $\exists$ at least $2$ $i$'s such that $in_{>}(h_ig_i)=\mu$. Say $j,k$ be $2$ such elements of $\{1,2,\dots, r \} $. 
 Set $\displaystyle{}L_j:=\frac{\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_j,in_>g_k)}{in_>g_j}$ and define $L_k$ similarly. $S(g_{j},g_k)=L_jg_j-L_kg_k$.  Let $\eta$ be such that $\eta \cdot \operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_j,in_>g_k)=\mu$.
 Using the division algorithm and Buchberger's condition, we get an expression of the form $S(g_j,g_k)=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^rp_ig_i}$ with $in_{>} p_ig_i\leq in_> f \ \forall \ i$. (the remainder term is $0$). It follows that $\displaystyle{}in_{>}S(g_i,g_j) =\max_{1\leq i \leq r}in_>( p_ig_i ) \implies in _> \left (\eta p_ig_i \right )\leq in _{>}\eta S(g_j,g_k)<\eta\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_j,in_>g_k)=\mu  $
Now $$f=\sum_{i=1}^rh_ig_i=\sum_{i=1}^rh_ig_i+\eta S(g_j,g_k)-\eta \sum_{i=1}^rp_ig_i= \sum_{i\neq j,k}(h_i-\eta p_i)g_i +(h_j +\eta L_j -\eta p_j)g_j+(h_k -\eta L_j -\eta p_k)g_k $$
If $i\neq j,k$, we see that $\displaystyle{}in_> (h_i-\eta p_i) \begin{matrix}=\mu & \text{if} & in_> (h_ig_i)=\mu \\ < \mu & \text{if} & in_> (h_ig_i)<\mu   \end{matrix}$ 
Also $\displaystyle{}in_> (\eta L_jg_j)=\eta \frac{\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_j,in_>g_k)}{in_>g_j}in_> g_j=\eta\operatorname{lcm} (in_>g_j,in_>g_k)=\mu $ and similarly for $in _>(\eta L_k g_k)$ 
 It follows that $in _> (h_k-\eta L_k -\eta p_k )g_k< \mu $  and $in _> (h_j-\eta L_j -\eta p_j )g_j\not > \mu $. 
Thus we get an expression $f=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^r}h_i'g_i $ where $\#\{i : in_> (h_i'g_i)=\mu \}<\#\{i : in_> (h_ig_i)=\mu \}$ This contradicts the choice of the representation, $f=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^rh_ig_i}$. 
 Thus we must have if $f\in I$, $in_>f \in \langle \{in_>g_i : i=1(1)r \} \rangle$

Our professor gave us a sketch of the proof along these lines and asked us to fill in the details. I shall be grateful if someone can point out if there are any gaps/mistakes. Alternative approaches/comments/simplifications etc are also most welcome.

Comment: have you been able to figure this proof out?

Comment: Do you see any gap in my argument?

Comment: I am going through gröbner basis and I found the similar proof taught by a CMI professor. I am basically stuck in the part why is $in_>(S(g_1,g_2))=max_{1\le i\le r}in_>(p_i.g_i)$?

Comment: @smita In a sum of polynomials how can the leading term occur? Isn't it the maximum of the leading terms of polynomials in that sum? The only issue is when two (or more) polynomials have the same leading monomials and the sum of their coefficients is zero. But then one can get rid of this part from the sum.

Comment: This is where I am having a doubt suppose on the right hand side the leading term cancels out then how can $in(S(g_1,g_2))=max\{in(p_i.g_i)\}$?

Comment: If the leading terms cancel out, then just delete them from the sum until this phenomenon can't occur again.

Comment: So if this happens we consider new polynomials of the form $p_i'.q_i'$ where $q_i'=q_i-\mu$?

Comment: Why not?${}{}{}$